# Are forecasts from SPSS Time Series Modeler transfer functions ex post or ex ante?

Tags: time-series, spss

I've fit a transfer function in SPSS Time Series Modeler from a training set and output the predictions.  I get predictions for both my training set (which was used to produce the model) and my test set (which comes after the training set).

What I can't find in the documentation is whether the predicted values for the test set use the observed data (ex post forecasts) or if the test set predictions are made solely from the transfer function model continuing on without further input (ex ante forecast).

My impression is that it's ex post (that it's using the test set observations, at least for the transfer function input variables) because when I try getting the predictions when those variables are not in the data set I get an error.  However, I would like to have some confirmation that that's what is going on, as it's always possible error messages could be for something else.

Comment: _Estimation period_ obeys USE or FILTER commands. _Forecast period_ always begins from the end of estimation period and goes up to the case of date specified in PREDICT THRU command (which could be beyond the dataset end). Variables output into the dataset get values for both estimation and forecast periods.

Comment: This was an instant response. Please consult SPSS documentation (Command Syntax Reference and SPSS Statistics Algorithms) for the corresponding time series command.